# Custom (internal) binary package in R - update to recent version

Tags: r, package

New to R overall and am trying to install an old package by some former employees. I have been working with a company that has some legacy R packages (3.4.1), and am trying to install them into my latest version of R (3.6.1).

I get the following error when I try this :

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘XXX’:
package ‘XXX’ was installed by an R version with different internals; 
it needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version
```

The current package is a win.binary (ZIP) file, but am unsure if I have access to the source code or if it still exists in a shared location.

I understand a work around is to install 3.4.1 but that's not feasible long term. Is there a way I can unpackage a win.binary back into its source code to be able to re-package under the latest version of R?